# UICollectionView - How to 'wait' to load cell?

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, swift4

```
    cv.reloadData()
    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: self.index, section: 0)
        self.cv.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)

        let cell = self.cv.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CustomCell
        cell?.indicate()
    }
```

At the line `let cell = self.cv.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CustomCell` cell sometime is loaded - sometime is nil.

How to ensure to every time `cell` have actual cell item?
Thanks